# @Bean annotation context config cashing data

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javafx-2

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.zenjava.com/2011/10/24/multiple-controllers-with-shared-resources/

And my question is (regarding Spring annotation context configuration):
why @Bean annotation is cashing data between all Person instances? And how to avoid that if needed?
Sorry for trivial question but I'm new to Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is actually happening, is that all beans defined in Spring are Singleton by default (not in a Design Pattern sense, but in a container managed sense, meaning that Spring will reuse the same Person instance whenever it needs a dependency of class Person.class).

If you need to have different instance of Person injected into each dependency, you need to specify `@Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE)`